# Dedicating RAM to video card

Tags: graphics-cards, memory

Not sure if this is the best forum for this. If it is not, can you point me in the general direction of the best one?

I would like to play a video game that needs 1GB of dedicated RAM to the graphics card. When I use the "Can I run it" site, it tells me that there is only 32 MB of dedicated graphics RAM. When I run the game it is unbearably choppy and I am not able to play it.

I have included Device Manager and dxdiag screenshots. The Display screenshot says that I have just about 4GB of RAM for graphics. I have checked all the drivers, they are up to date. I have attempted to go in to the BIOS and change the amount, as recommended by some Google searchage, but there is no option in there that I can find. I've selected every single option I can, just in case it's lurking somewhere I wouldn't expect to find it. Is there anything else that I can do, other than replacing the card, to satisfy the game requirements?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That graphics card is horribly underpowered for any modern game. I would advise you to get a newer/better one (such as a 750Ti). It would be better to just plug the monitor into the mainboard graphics plug, as even intel's integrated GPU will outperform the 8500 GT and *might* be able to play some modern games somewhat smoothly.

TL;DR: There is no way to get a reasonably modern game running smoothly on hardware released in 2007.

EDIT: If you downvoted, please explain why

Comment: Thank you. Question about the RAM, the computer has 8GB installed, so where does the 4GB come from?

Comment: Goto your start menu, right click Computer, and select properties. It will show there how much installed RAM you have as well. Maybe one of your sticks or DIMM slots aren't functioning

Comment: I have edited the original question to show the system information (I had to remove one of the other pictures, since I can only share 2 of them apparently). 

Side note, I did not down vote. I am satisfied with your response, though I still don't understand about the RAM, since I have 8GB showing and am running 64bit.

Comment: Did you install the 8500GT as an addon card? if so, remove it. the integrated one built into the computer is better (not by much, but it might be enough)